# Several columns of code horizontally (side-by-side and same file) in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to have several columns of code side-by-side in Visual Studio 2008? And if so where to tweak that?

Comment: Are you aiming to compare code? Then use a diff tool, not multiple columns...

Comment: What do you mean diff tool? And yes the purpose is to compare code with really wide screens 27+ it is a lot of sort of "whitespace"

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one file open, you can create a new Tab-Group by clicking on Window->New Horizontal Tab Group / New Vertical Tab Group. This allows to edit several files without switching.

Answer (score 1):

right click on the code window tab, select move to next tab.

Alternatively, you can choose window --> split to make a verticle row split.

I am not sure if this still works, but if you go to tools -> options --> workspace (or environment, something like that), you can choose MDI view. Then you get an MDI interface instead of tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Not within a single window.

However, you can place two documents side by side by opening them both and choosing Window -> New Vertical Tab group (VS2008) or Window -> Split (VS2005).

(You can also edit columnar text sing Alt-drags to select rectangular regions of the text for copy & paste, but I doubt that's what you're asking for)